# Insert Row Below Instead of Above

Tags: excel, vba

This code inserts a row as I want it to, but it inserts the row above the row containing 19 in column I and I want to insert the row below.  How can I modify this code to insert the row below?

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim lRow As Long

For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row To 3 Step -1
If Cells(lRow, "I") = "19" Then Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert
Next lRow
```

Comment: `Rows(lRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert`

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code might do the trick:

```
Rows(lRow).Resize(1).Insert xlUp
```

And if you need to insert more rows you can change the "1" with the appropriate number.

Answer (score 0):

You simply add 1 to the `lRow` variable to specify the row you want.

```
Rows(lRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert
```